# Divide services into different pods

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

I have a project with multiple services using spring boot.

I would like to divide my services into different parts such as each part uses a different pod in deployment.

Is there any way to do it, without creating new projects?

NB : services use many similar methods and have same conf.

Edit :

I think I have asked my question in a wrong way. Let me try to explain : I have a springboot application, with services, controllers, crons, repositories... On deployment the 10 pods I have are always using max capacity.

The main goal is to reduce the usage of pods capacity. One idea that I had is to switch to a multi module architecture such as all modules (module_A, module_B, module_C) have a common parent. module_C and module_B import module_A as a dependency (they need functions, services and entities in module_A).

The thing is that I am not sure if this will help me achieve my goal by having multiple builds, so multiple images to deploy independently on pods.

I would like to know if there is any other way (maybe spring annotation) to divide the project nad deploy different parts of the project (only what is needed) at the same time.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the single Springboot application as if it was different sets of sub-services by doing the following: (This assumes a 'service' is a route)

- code in Rest Client URL configuration at the route level
- calling specific services on specific pods and
- configuring calls between pods
- deploying the same application across all the pods

For example, if we have the following routes in the complete application:
/route1, /route2, /route3, /route4, /route5, /route6

Only only make calls to /route1, /route2 from external on pod1.

Configure pod1 to call pod2 url for /route3 and /route4 calls

Configure pod2 to call pod3 url for /route5 and /route6 calls

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your time, but I think that my question was poorly  worded.